# Calculate Subnet mask from IP address range manually

Tags: ip-address

How can I calculate Subnet mask from IP address range manually?

For example IP addresses from 212.92.32.00 to 212.92.63.255, what is the mask in decimal dot format?

Comment: do you want to calculate it programatically or ... ? if you just want to calculate it now , here - http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: I want to know how can I calculate it manually on paper

Comment: there is already question about , have a look at http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Answer (score 1):

The **first** and the **last** IPv4 addresses of the subnet satisfy the following:

- they have identical first N bits
- the first address has remaining (32-N) bits equal to 0
- the last address has remaining (32-N) bits equal to 1

In this case, the netmask is simply /N. In your example, the addresses are:

11010100.01011100.001**00000.00000000** and

11010100.01011100.001**11111.11111111**

so:

- your addresses have first 19 bits equal
- the first address has last 13 bits equal to 0
- the last address has last 13 bits equal to 1

So, your netmask is **/19**, or **11111111.11111111.11100000.00000000**, or **255.255.224.0**.

Answer (score 0):

This IP range belongs to Class C means N.N.N.H (N means Network ID's and H means Host ID's) and Default Class C subset mask 255.255.255.0. In binary format 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000.
Here 8 Host bits  2x2x2x2x2x2x2x2 = 256 (usable 254 only because 2 hosts not usable one for Network and one for Broadcast)
Now first sub-net as follows:

Network:   212.92.32.0/24
Broadcast: 212.92.32.255
HostMin:   212.92.32.1 ----- (usable IP starting)
HostMax:   212.92.32.254 -----(usable IP ending)
Netmask:   255.255.255.0
Hosts/Net: 254

and up-to  212.92.63.255